# Enviar un correo con PHP en localhost

Tags: php, email, localhost

**Aclaración:** No busco subir los scripts a un hosting, son meramente procesos locales.

tengo una serie de scripts que trabajan de manera local.
Todos se ejecutan en cierto momento y funcionan perfecto.

Ahora estoy creando el envío automatizado de informes/reportes diarios,
En donde me he topado con un freno, el envío de correos.

Actualmente he dado con varias guías donde todas terminan en un código básico,
muy similar al siguiente:

```
<?php
// Datos para el correo
$destinatario = "correo@ejemplo.com";
$asunto = "Asunto";
$carta = "Prueba de envío de correo";

// Enviando Mensaje
mail($destinatario, $asunto, $carta);
?>
```

Pero al momento de testear esto, me aparece el siguiente error:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost"
>
>  port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Y buscando guías sobre ello, decían el a .ini y activar estas caracterísitcas,
pero aún después de activadas, el error continúa.

¿Que más necesito para hacer envíos de correo desde un ambiente local?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Failed to connect to mailserver](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102861/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver)

Comment: @JuanRivera no por que ahí lo quieren subir a un hosting, yo no lo subiré a un hosting

Comment: Aunque se este usando un complemento externo `PHPMailer` la solucion en si esta para un hosting, local o servidor. Si no quieres lo anterior dicho, encontre una solucion en ingles [mailserver-localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25) donde dice que se debe instalar un componente respecto a tu sistema operativo, para ejecutar un servidor de correo localmente

Comment: No es que no lo quiera, es que no ha funcionado usar PHPMailer, por que al parecer falta algo más. Instañé PHPMailer con Composer, pero con eso no basta

Comment: ¿Cuál sistema operativo tiene localhost?

Comment: @Sal dije respecto a su sistema operativo (windows,linux,etc)

Comment: Pero en si la respuesta esta en *Instalar un componente para ejecutar un servidor de correo localmente*

Comment: Puedes consultar el servicio gratuito que ofrece google para enviar correos electronicos estando en localhost

Comment: Estoy en ello actualmente. es cosa de buscar...

Comment: Puedes usar librerias de envios de mail, tipo PHPMailer. Aqui tienes alguna pregunrta que han realizado sobre su uso https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149464/phpmailer-no-se-puede-conectar-al-host-smtp/149791#149791

Comment: Buenas, gracias por el apoyo. Lo que realmente sucedóa, no era el mal uso de PHPMailer o el tener que subirlo a un hosting. Sino configurar un servidor smtp primero. Esto me lo sugirieron en el chat, asi que marcaré lo realizado más tarde como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya lo han mencionado en los comentarios a tu pregunta, puedes subirlo a un hosting y desde allí realizar las pruebas necesarias de tu servicio de correo.

Otra opción que a mi me ha funcionado, es instalar "fake" servidor de correos en tu equipo:

Yo recomiendo utilizar [FakeSMTP](http://nilhcem.com/FakeSMTP/). Ya que es fácil de utilizar y de configurar y puedes guardar los correos de pruebas para algún propósito.

Comment: No me sirve subirlo a un hosting, es lo que he mencionado anteriormente. Lo aclararé mejor en la publicación. Revisaré lo de fakeSMTP ahora.

Comment: Desde localhost esto se puede hacer, pero si o si necesitas un servidor, no necesario un hosting, puedes usar el servicio que ofrece google